# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I tried to assign div side by side in my react website. However,I received the error `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error`.

This is my toolbar in my react website

```
let EnhancedTableToolbar = props => {
  const { numSelected, classes ,deletefunc} = props;

  return (
    <Toolbar
      className={classNames(classes.root, {
        [classes.highlight]: numSelected > 0,
      })}
    >
      <div className={classes.title}>
        {numSelected > 0 ? (
          <Typography color="inherit" variant="subtitle1">
            {numSelected} selected
          </Typography>
        ) : (
          <Typography variant="h6" id="tableTitle">
            User List
          </Typography>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.spacer} />
      <div className={classes.actions}>
        {numSelected > 0 ? (
        <div>
        <div style="width: 100px; float:right;">
          <Tooltip title="Delete">
            <IconButton aria-label="Delete">
              <DeleteIcon onClick={() => { if (window.confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete '+numSelected +' item?')) {deletefunc()} } }>
              </DeleteIcon>
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
         </div>
         <div style="width: 100px; float:right;">
          <Tooltip title="Edit">
            <IconButton aria-label="Edit">
              <EditIcon>
              </EditIcon>
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
          </div>
         </div> 


        ) : (
          <Tooltip title="Filter list">
            <IconButton aria-label="Filter list">
              <FilterListIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        )}


      </div>
    </Toolbar>
  );
};
```

I received the error when I set the width to 100px and float to right in my delete button and edit button. The code will work if I never set the width and float. However,it div by up down instead of side by side. Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not how you define [inline styles in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style).

> The `style` attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased
>   properties rather than a CSS string.

Try this instead:

```
<div style={{ width: '100px', float: 'right' }}>
```

Comment: It solve the error. However, it still div by up down instead of left right. Do you know how to assign div side by side?

Comment: Try `display: 'inline-block'`, instead of `float` thing.

Comment: Your overall layout is faulty then, try to stretch their parent `div` (not sure why it's even there). If you were looking for a way to wrap siblings so that React doesn't throw exception - use `React.Fragment`.

Comment: It worked if I remove <div className={classes.spacer} />. However,the alignment is left if I remove this